# Laravel 4.2 get data from main with only pivot data?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have a table called emails, that has a pivot table and in that pivot table there is a column called "hash". Is there away to email that that hash belongs too?

I have tried this,

```
$email = Email::with(array('projects' => function($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('hash', '=', $id); 
}))->get();
```

But this returns all the rows from the email table and not just the one that matches the hash. Is there a way to search the pivot table and get back the row that relates from the email table?

Comment: Sounds like you want the wherePivot() function.

Answer (score 0):

When you define the `projects` method in your `Email` class you can add the pivot columns to the model by using the [`withPivot`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) method:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Project')->withPivot('hash');
}
```

You can then use it in the following way:

```
$email = Email::with(['projects' => /* ... */])->get();

foreach ($email as $item) {
    echo $item->title; // regular field on `email`
    echo $item->pivot->hash; // field on the pivot table
}
```